# How to add Network Interfaces to a Combobox and resolve ip based on selected interface?

Tags: c#, combobox, network-interface

For practice i want to create a selectable dropdown box with available Network Interfaces ( localhost ), and upon selecting one of them there should be an ip resolution ( writes ip4 to one textbox and ip6 to the next box ) for that selected interface

So far i have :

```
private void localhostip(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     var mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
            var moc = mc.GetInstances();

            foreach (var mo in moc)
            {
                if ((bool)mo["ipEnabled"])
                {
                     comboBox1.Items.Add(mo["Caption"].ToString());
                }
            }
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ACQUIRE THE IP4 & IP6 ADDRESSES
            string host = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);

            tblocalhost.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
            tblocalip.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
            tblocalhost.Text = host;


            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                tblocalip.Text = null;
                tblocalip6.Text = null;

                foreach (IPAddress ip4 in ips.Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
                {
                    tblocalip.Text = ip4.ToString();
                }

                foreach (IPAddress ip6 in ips.Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6))
                {
                    tblocalip6.Text = ip6.ToString();
                }
            }

            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                tblocalip.Text = null;
                tblocalip6.Text = null;

                foreach (IPAddress ip4 in ips.Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
                {
                    tblocalip.Text = ip4.ToString();
                }

                foreach (IPAddress ip6 in ips.Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6))
                {
                    tblocalip6.Text = ip6.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Notice : localhostip is executed on Form launch.

So now how do i bind the choosing of the Interface Index to the actual checking of that Interface's IP ?

And if possible suggest corrections/additions to my code, to keep it simple and understandable for me , i dont want to just copy someone else's code and be done, i wanna learn

Comment: Hi I just want to check with you before answering, I believe you simply forgot the paranthesis for the first error. it should be `comboBox1.Items.Add(mo["Caption"].ToString());`

Comment: Fix that, then subscribe to the OnSelectedIndexChanged (or similar event) of the ComboBox and handle the event as you were. Would you like any more help with that side of it?

Comment: Also when writing the text to the textboxes for the IP. instead of `tblocalip.Text = ip4.ToString();` do something like this `tblocalip.Text += ip4.ToString() + "\r\n";`. The current way is setting the text, you need to add the text to the existing text each iteration. Notice the += operator instead of +. The `\r\n` simply makes a new line.

Comment: wow that one parenthesis was the problem.
so now i tried to use if(combobox1.selectedindex == 1) set textboxes to null and then do the ip resolution and write the ip address inside the box, but its not doing it

also doesnt += add to the existing ? i want it to only show one ip adress and if another interface is selected only one adress again.

Comment: No problem, the combobox index is zero based, so I would recommend setting it to 0 and only after checking the `combobox1.Items.Count > 0` otherwise leave it as default (-1). I'll look at the other things you mentioned now.

Comment: i updated the Code and the Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When getting adapter names and IP addresses, I suggest something like the following:

By storing them in a dictionary you can access them by their adapter name.

Please see my comments for detailed explanation on the process I used.

I hope this helps, I tried to be thorough with the comments.

### Notes for the method for storing the adapter names and IPs

```
//create a dictionary storing the name and address of each adapter
public Dictionary<string,IPAddress> ip4ByAdapter = new Dictionary<string,IPAddress>();
public Dictionary<string,IPAddress> ip6ByAdapter = new Dictionary<string,IPAddress>();

void GetIpsAndAdapters()
{
    //Get the network interfaces
    NetworkInterface[] netInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    //don't forget to clear the combo box
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();

    foreach(NetworkInterface adapter in netInterfaces)
    {
        //get the IP Properties for short hand
        IPInterfaceProperties ipProps = adapter.GetIPProperties();

        //set a default value of 0.0.0.0
        IPAddress ipv4 = new IPAddress(0); 

        //if it has one, store the ipv4 of the current adapter
        if(ipProps.UnicastAddresses.Count > 1)
            ipv4 = ipProps.UnicastAddresses[1].Address;

        //set a default value of 0.0.0.0
        IPAddress ipv6 = new IPAddress(0);

        //if it has one, store the ipv6 of the current adapter
        if (ipProps.UnicastAddresses.Count > 0)
            ipv6 = ipProps.UnicastAddresses[0].Address;

        //store the matching pair of adapter and ip address in dictionary
        //check for duplicates (loopbacks perhaps) and ignore them
        if(!ip4ByAdapter.ContainsKey(adapter.Name))
            ip4ByAdapter.Add(adapter.Name, ipv4);

        //same for ipv6
        if(!ip6ByAdapter.ContainsKey(adapter.Name))
            ip6ByAdapter.Add(adapter.Name, ipv6);

        comboBox1.Items.Add(adapter.Name);
    }
}
```

### Notes for the comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged Event

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if we haven't selected an item yet, just do nothing
    if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 || comboBox1.SelectedItem is null)
        return;

    //reset the textboxes, just to an empty string
    tblocalip.Text = "";
    tblocalip6.Text = "";

    //if the Dictionary contains a matching adapter to the one selected in the combo box
    if(ip4ByAdapter.ContainsKey(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()))
    {
        //then show it
        tblocalip.Text = ip4ByAdapter[comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()].ToString();
    }

    //same for ipv6
    if(ip6ByAdapter.ContainsKey(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()))
    {
        tblocalip6.Text = ip6ByAdapter[comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: IPAddress ipv4 = adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses[1].Address; Throws me a "system.argumentoutofrangeexception" 
so i changed it to 0 as the index, but now both textboxes contain my ipv6 address, it updates whenever i change another adapter but again no ipv4 to be seen
ive checked the whole thing again and again and i cant figure out why is it showing ipv6 only

Comment: @JohnLinaer I have amended my answer to account for adapters that may not have a valid ipv4 or ipv6 address or both, I ran this through my debugger to ensure it would work across all three of my adapters.

Comment: I'm heading to bed but I will take a look tomorrow if you have any trouble. Cheers and good luck.

Comment: Interesting, i found out now that if i have ipv6 disabled, the ipv4 box shows 0.0.0.0 and ipv6 box shows the ipv4 address. However if i enable ipv6 then it shows both correctly in their correct box.
But honestly this already works fine for me. I dont want to make it overly complicated as this is mostly to learn code not a commercial use.
Adding special exceptions, specific scenarios that would make the displaying perfect i can do myself, what matters is i learned very awesome things from this for which i thank you immensely.